# CAGradientLayer as layerClass for UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, calayer

I am trying to use CAGradientLayer as the root layer of a UIView subclass via overriding the layerClass class method of UIView. I have done the EXACT same thing for a UIButton subclass, and it all works perfectly, however for UIView, I do not see a gradient, I just see the default white view background.

Here is my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIView+NBStyle.h"

@interface NBStylizedView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* highColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor* lowColor;

@end

...

#import "NBStylizedView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation NBStylizedView

@synthesize highColor;
@synthesize lowColor;

+ (Class) layerClass {
    return [CAGradientLayer class];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self.highColor && self.lowColor) {
        CAGradientLayer* gLayer = (CAGradientLayer*) self.layer;
        [gLayer setColors:
         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
          (id)[self.highColor CGColor], 
          (id)[self.lowColor CGColor], nil]];
    }   
    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)setHighColor:(UIColor*)color {
    highColor = color;
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setLowColor:(UIColor*)color {
    lowColor = color;
    [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Can anyone shed some light on where my problem lies?

Comment: You should be setting the gradient layer's colours in your setter methods for the high and low colours, not the drawRect. Note also that the `colors` property is implicitly animated, so you should set it inside a CATransaction with disableActions set to YES

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, and saw no gradient at first either.  If I set the view's background color to clearColor in the view's awakeFromNib method, it worked.

Comment: This works, but I'm not quite sure why, i.e. what is different between UIButton and UIView in this case? Accepting this answer, but would still love some further explanation from anyone.

Comment: @nickbona, If you log the background color of a UIView you get "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.75 0.75 0.75 1", but if you log the background color of a UIButton you get NULL -- I don't know why it's that way, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

Because the default opaque of the view is YES, that means, the view must draw a background before drawing the content. If you set customView.opaque = NO; after the view's initiation. As to Button, the default opaque is No, and you can see in IB the Clears Graphics Context is YES.